# How to set text in particular place in RichTextBox in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I just want to set my `text in particular place in RichtextBox` in wpf:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionLength = text_length;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

please try this.i hope that it will help you.

```
RichTextBox richtexbox=(RichTextBox)(FindResource("richbox1"));      
richtexbox.Padding = new Thickness(15, 10, 12, 15);
```